# Probability: What ist the expected value of the number of comparisons made during a linear search?

Tags: probability

I would like to propose the following problem:

A linear search is performed to check whether a given name 'N' is on a list.  The list contains 10 distinct names.

The details:

The search begins by comparing the first name on the list to the given name 'N', if there is a match, the search ends and the number of comparisons, $i$, is recorded, in this case $i = 1$.

If there is no match, the given name 'N' is compared to the next name on the list, if there is a match, the search ends and the number of comparisons done thus far is recorded (here $i = 2$).

We continue in this way, until either a match is made OR we hit the last (tenth) name on the list and find no match, in this case $i = 10\>$ is recorded (in fact, whether there is a match to the last name on the list or not).

And now the question:

If all the names on the list are equally likely to match the given name 'N' and if the odds of there being no match to 'N' on the list is $L$, what is the expected value of the number $i$ (i.e. the number of comparisons made during a search)?

In particular, given $L = 0.4$, what is the expected value of $i$?

Many thanks in advance,

Alfred

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  Assuming $N$ is in the list, what is the expected number of comparisons?  Call it $c$.  Assuming it is not in the list, the number of comparisons is $10$  So you have the over expectation of $0.4c +0.6 \cdot 10$

Added:  Let the chance that a given name matches be $p$.  What is the chance that it is on the list at least once?  By using the fact that the chance the name is on the list is given as $0.6$ you can evaluate $p$.  Then the chance you only look at one name is $p$, the chance you look at two is ????, at three is ????. The chance you look at $10$ is a bit different-it depends on whether you roll the chance of not finding the name into this calculation or leave it to the side.

Comment: Actually, you were correct, I made the typo (I typed L = 0.6 in the original version) but I have since corrected it.  Thanks again.  :)

Comment: So the initial problem can be divided into two problems:

i)  Find the value of p = the chance that a given name on the list is a match.

ii)  Find the chance that you only look at one name, then find the chance that you look at exactly two, three etc.

As for 10, that would just be the chance of having not gotten a match in the previous 9.

Comment: That is correct.  When I first read it I though you were guaranteed that the name would only be on the list once, if at all.  In that case you would average $5.5$ names to look at if it is on the list and the problem is much easier.  Here if it is on the list you are more likely to look at fewer names because you stop when you find the first one.  If $p$ were very small, the chance of the name being on twice would be very very small and you could ignore it.

Comment: The 10 names on the list are to be considered distinct.  Hence, as you say, the name would only appear on the list once, if at all.

The fact that you stop as soon as you find the first one, that would seem to make the outcome less than the average of the outcomes = 5.5, that's what you seem to be saying and I would agree.

Comment: No, as I read it now, each entry on the list has a chance of $p$ being the name of interest.  It is possible that the name is on the list multiple times.  If $p$ were $\frac 12$, the chance the name was on the list would be $\frac {1023}{1024}$ and on average you would only check (about) two names before finding it.

Comment: I am sorry for the unclear description.  I should have stated it more clearly, the 10 names on the list are distinct and I have now edited the problem to clarify this.

Comment: In that case,as you said, you have $c=5.5$ and are done with the first answer.

Comment: Thanks, I am thinking of the strategy you proposed earlier using p:

Chance of looking exactly once:  p; chance of looking exactly twice:  (1-p) * p;  chance of looking exactly three times:   (1-p)^2 * p *  ...  chance of looking exactly nine times:  (1-p)^8 * p and chance of looking ten times:  (1-p)^9.

Is this approach correct?

Also, to find p, one could say:  Chances of there not being a match at all = (1-p)^10 = L and then isolate p in this equation.

Is all this mathematical reasoning correct?

Many thanks,
Alfred

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I was thinking.  In the last, the right side should be $1-L$ because you have calculated the chance that the name is not on the list.  Now take tenth roots and you will get $p$.

Comment: Thanks, Ross.  That's really cool.  :)

The correct equation for $p$ is then $(1-p)^(10) = 1 - L$,

and I guess the expected value of $i$ (the number of comparisons) would then be

$p * 1 + (1 – p) * p * 2 + (1 – p)^2 * p * 3 +  ...  + (1 – p)^8 * p * 9  +  (1 – p)^9 * 10$

If this answer could indeed be confirmed to be true, you folks would have made my day  ––Alfred

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  As a $\LaTeX$ hint, when you want multicharacter things like exponents, put them in braces, so x^{10} gives $x^{10}$ instead of $x^10$

Comment: Yes, I was having a bit of trouble yesterday trying to display $(1–p)^{10}$ correctly, thanks for clearing this up for me too!  :)

Any others mathematically inclined out there wishing to verify or criticize my formula?  That would be so much appreciated.  BTW, Ross do you major in maths?  ––  Alfred